# Strange that .ssh/authorized_keys will not work if it is a chmod of 664?

Tags: ssh

I was trying to set up automatic log in using ssh, but it didn't work, and saw the file as

```
rw-rw-r--
```

on the server, so it is `664`.  But it can't automatic log in, until I chmod to 600 for it, and then all of a sudden, it can automatic log in.  Is there a requirement that says it must be `600` for it to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

644 is fine too. It just can't be group and/or other writable.

Comment: you mean it cannot be group or other writable... is there a doc that says so... and it is weird that instead of a warning, i get back a "require password to login"...

Comment: There is no mechanism for sshd to give you a "warning message" (or any message) during the authentication stage. So it just rejects you.

Answer (score 2):

Setting StrictModes no in sshd_config will remove this restriction. But it's not recommended.

Comment: That requires root access, which I'm not sure the OP has. ;-)